# No exception when SOAP service is offline, using PHP

Tags: php, soap

I have a question, I am developing a web page and I communicate with a server via SOAP. My code is in PHP.

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array("location" => "$serverpath",
                                 "uri"      => "$namespace",
                                 "style"    => SOAP_RPC,
                                 "use"      => SOAP_ENCODED ));
try
{
 $returnedValue = $client->getInfo($user);

} catch (SoapException $exception)
{

 $returnedIDValue = "Caught Soap Exception: $exception\n";

}
```

When the SOAP services are offline, I do not get any exception; the program just stops.

Any suggestions? I would like to handle gracefully that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to catch a SoapFault instead of a SoapException?

Although it's strange, because if I don't catch the SoapFault with your code I get a fatal error:
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unable to parse URL in... Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('

Replacing the SoapException with SoapFault fixes this error.

If you don't get the error, check that you have error_reporting at E_ALL in PHP configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for your time, that worked!! Regards from Guadalajara Mexico :)